# In a database program what do these lines of code mean and do?

Tags: python, database, sqlite

In a database program what does these lines of code mean and do?

```
conn=sqlite3.connect(filename)
c=conn.cursor()

conn.commit()
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could think of `conn = sqlite3.connect(filename)` as creating a connection, or a reference, to that database specified in the filename. So anytime you carry out an action with `conn`, it will be an action performed on the database specified by `filename`.

`c = conn.cursor()` is a cursor object, which allows you to carry out SQL queries on the database. It is created using a call on the `conn` variable created earlier, and so is a cursor object for that specific database. This is most commonly useful for its .execute() method, which is used to execute SQL commands on the database.

`conn.commit()` 'commits' the changes to the database; that is, when this command is called, any changes that had been made by the cursor will be saved to the database.